# NodeJS Agent similar to Java agent

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create node agent similar to java agent to gather the performance of running nodejs application

I found appmetrics npm package and it works fine , if I include that to the exisitng nodejs script but I am trying to run as an agent without modifying existing nodejs script

Sample which explains my issue which works fine

```
var http = require("http");
var appmetrics = require('appmetrics');
var monitoring = appmetrics.monitor();

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8083);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8083/');

monitoring.on('initialized', function (env) {
    env = monitoring.getEnvironment();
    for (var entry in env) {
        console.log(entry + ':' + env[entry]);
    };
});

monitoring.on('cpu', function (cpu) {
    console.log('[' + new Date(cpu.time) + '] CPU: ' + cpu.process);
});
```

Issue is to have appmetric separately and nodejs hello world script separately and running them together

helloworld.js

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8083);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8083/');
```

monitor.js

```
var appmetrics = require('appmetrics');
var monitoring = appmetrics.monitor();

monitoring.on('initialized', function (env) {
    env = monitoring.getEnvironment();
    for (var entry in env) {
        console.log(entry + ':' + env[entry]);
    };
});

monitoring.on('cpu', function (cpu) {
    console.log('[' + new Date(cpu.time) + '] CPU: ' + cpu.process);
});
```

Trying to run above mentioned two scripts at a time using 
node which is not working

node helloworld.js && node monitor.js

Comment: Would it work for monitor.js to `require(helloworld.js)`?

Comment: No I am trying make that script like java agent to run outside that script in fact for any other nodejs script